# Rounding off to any given value python

Tags: python, rounding

I have a list that contains values generated randomly. Each value of that list corresponds to one particular parameter like distance, time and so on. 
I have created a function that will round off each value of that list to the number of digits entered by the user:

```
def round_list(list_x):
    for i in range(0, len(list_x)):
        incrementer = raw_input('Enter the increment value: ')
        list_x[i] = np.round(list_x[i], int(incrementer))
    return list_x

x = round_list(x)
print(x)
```

But this will only work to set the decimal points right?
What if the user wants it to be rounded off to every `0.25` or every `0.03`?
How would I incorporate that? I don't think `round()` can accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounding to the nearest fractional value (say 0.25) can be done by dividing by the fraction, then rounding to the nearest integer, then multiplying by the fraction.

Something like this:

```
def roundToBase(num, base):
    return np.round(float(num) / base, 0) * base

print(roundToBase(1.3,0.25)) # 1.25

# also works for non-fractional bases,
# eg round to nearest multiple of 5:
print(roundToBase(26,5)) # 25
```

Comment: The main problem here is that your code needs to figure out the denominator, but you haven't shown how!

Comment: So the user must enter only step sizes right? instead of mentioning 2 decimal places, they must enter steps of 0.01?

Comment: yes, rounding to a base of `0.01` is the same as rounding to 2dp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def round(number, nearest):

    if ((number % nearest) / nearest) < 0.5:
        return (number - (number % nearest))
    else:
        return ((number - (number % nearest)) + nearest)
```

Explanation:

The `if` checks if the the difference between the number and the most previous multiple of `nearest` is less than half of `nearest`. If it is, it means that the number needs to be rounded down, which is why, if it's `True`, it returns the most previous multiple of `nearest`. If it's `False`, it returns (the most previous multiple of `nearest`) + `nearest`.

Comment: nearest here is the user input for increment right? I will try this

Comment: @Potato Yes (I think) ... `nearest` is the 0.25 or 0.03 you mention in your example.